# Laravel Posting my request value that is utf8 in ascii

Tags: php, laravel, utf-8

Why is my Laravel application posting a utf8 character ® in it's ascii form ("Â®")?  Is there a way to pass the utf8 version of my input strings to the $request body rather than ascii?

If I send data through my form to my post controller and dyndump the response, it gives me the ascii version, Â®.

```
<input type="text" name="field" id="business_name" class="form-control" value="®"  placeholder="">
```

More details:

- Laravel Version 5.8.14
- PHP default_charset is set to utf8
- Is the page set to utf8?  Yes
- Is the Database configured for utf8?  It is, but this happens before hitting the database.  The issue is seen before it even hits the model.

Any more details you need just let me know.

Comment: There is no "ASCII form" of `®` since what most people consider "ASCII" is any character with a codepoint/ordinal value <128 in UTF8 and most western-european encodings where the latin alphabet and common punctuation lives. `®` does not fall into that category, and therefore can and will be represented differently in different character sets. For example, if you take a UTF8 string containing `®` and view it as iso8859-1/cp1252 you get the exact `Â®` mojibake you've quoted.

Comment: What you _actually_ want is going to be either converting your UTF-8 data into output compatible with what is rendering the text, aka [`mb_convert_encoding()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding), or adjusting the thing that is rendering the text expect UTF-8 rather than cp1252/iso8859-1. While there _is_ a lot of crossover between 1252 and 8859-1, they are not equivalent and you're going to need to explicitly know which one you're using.

Comment: Does the `value="®"` you provided show correctly in the frontend to begin with, before you submit anything?

Comment: Yes.  If you place it into the input field it shows properly and if you render after writing it to the database it looks fine.  I actually worked around the issue by decoding the value back to ®